# Combining 2 SELECT expression with LIMIT in both

Tags: android, sqlite, union, limit

I'm developing an Android application. I have a database table and I want to request two or more different SELECT expression with different WHERE condition and the same LIMIT for each expression. My query is like:

```
(SELECT * FROM questions WHERE level=1 LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM questions WHERE level=2 LIMIT 5)
```

When running application this query causes error that says:

```
near "UNION": syntax error: while compiling <here is my query>
```

When I omit the LIMIT it works well but LIMIT and ORDER BY don't work with UNION this way. My query is correct for MySQL according their [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html). But I couldn't find any SQLite documentation for my problem. So how should I query SQLite table for my needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    (
      SELECT * FROM  
       (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE level=1 LIMIT 5)
       UNION  
       SELECT * FROM  
       (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE level=2 LIMIT 5)
    )
```

Comment: Also If you want to make a order. you can use `Order By level` after the last parentheses.